# How can I setup an Authetication in Laravel within THE SAME TABLE?

Tags: laravel

I'ts just for practice and I need how to set up an Auth in Laravel but in the same table User. I know I have to use the default model User.php. I added my new column "type" where here I'm going to manage common users and admins. I edited and migrated that, also according to docs I created my guards and register providers but I don't know whats next. I know how to do it with another table but in the same table I have no idea how. I don't know how this Laravel's files works.

Comment: you can use `https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission` to run permissions and roles together. The documentation is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not an advanced programmer neither in medium level to understand git posts, not yet.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do, you can refer to the type on your auth calls to determine if the user is a user or an admin ie if (auth()->user->type == 'admin') {

Comment: Yes that's my idea with the same table, model and login page I want to manage users and admins. In many tutorials they show how to do it with another table, model and login, but yes! that's my idea. Do you have any tutorial or webpage to do it?